# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when try shiTomasiFeatureDetector filter in GPUImage2

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, gpuimage

UPDATE: i update my code last.

Seems like I have same issue with [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980462/gpuimage2-harriscornerdetector-not-calling-callback) but in different case. So I tried to use shiTomasiFeatureDetector filter from GPUImage2 framework in viewController.swift and i got EXC_BAD_ACCESS with code=1/code=2 in line `camera --> blendFilter --> renderView`. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage
import GPUImage
import AVFoundation
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var filterView: RenderView?
    var videoCamera: Camera?    

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        do {
            videoCamera = try Camera(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480, location: .backFacing)
            videoCamera!.runBenchmark = true
        } catch {
            videoCamera = nil
            print("Couldn't initialize camera with error: \(error)")
        }
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    // declare filters and crosshairs
    var shiTomasiFilter = ShiTomasiFeatureDetector()
    lazy var crosshairGenerator: CrosshairGenerator = {
        let generator = CrosshairGenerator(size:Size(width:480, height:640))
        generator.crosshairWidth = 15.0
        return generator
    }()
    let blendFilter = AlphaBlend()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //  re-declare camera using guard-statement
        guard let videoCamera = videoCamera else {
            let errorAlertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Error", comment: "Error"), message: "Couldn't initialize camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
            errorAlertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK"), style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(errorAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        if let view = self.filterView {
            //  gettin' corners
            shiTomasiFilter.cornersDetectedCallback = {
                corners in self.crosshairGenerator.renderCrosshairs(corners)
            }
            shiTomasiFilter.threshold = 0.1

            videoCamera --> shiTomasiFilter
            crosshairGenerator --> blendFilter

            videoCamera --> blendFilter --> view

            videoCamera.startCapture()
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Can i have any suggestion what happens with this?

The error link:
[error link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGQRh.png)

the error linked in Pipeline.swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answers!
All you have to do is check your identity inspector on your left (utilities bar), check whether class and module use 'RenderView' class and GPUImage modules or not.